# How to remove a nonexistent file from a Perforce changelist

Tags: perforce

I have the problem described here: [p4 Submit aborted Error - How to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268632/p4-submit-aborted-error-how-to-resolve)

That question was about how to find more information. In my case, I already know what's going on: the changelist contains a Vim swapfile (named .wr_en_hi.txt.swp) that doesn't exist anymore. So I see something like this:

```
add //depot/blah/.wr_en_hi.txt.swp#1
open for read: /blah/.wr_en_hi.txt.swp: No such file or directory
[...]
Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 117738'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
```

How do I tell Perforce to forget about that one file and just submit the rest of the changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p4 revert /blah/.wr_en_hi.txt.swp
```

Comment: And, subsequently, consider adding *.swp to your P4IGNORE file so this won't trip you up down the road.